# Table manipulation in R

Tags: r

have 2 tables.

In the first table, I have two columns. In the first colum , the values run from 1 to 2 million. In the second column, I have random numbers .

```
1 254
2 360
3 523
```

In the second table I have 2 columns with a start coordinate in the first and stop coordinate in the second. so, second is always greater than first item and the next row is greater than the current row.

```
520 600
620 750
760 795
```

Now , I want to split my first table based on the second table -- start and stop coordinate,like

```
520 --
521 --
522 -- till
600 --
```

and another table from 620

```
620 --
621 --
622 -- till
750 --
```

and another table from 760

```
760 --
761 --
762 -- till
795 --
```

and so on till 2 million.

Comment: You may want to take a look at `subset()`.

Comment: @Vincent: I am studying subset() documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  I'm sure there are many others.

```
# fake data
t1 <- cbind(1:20, sample(100:999, 20, TRUE))
t2 <- rbind(c(2, 4), c(6, 12), c(17, 18))

# list of matrices, each one a subset of t1 according to start and stop rows in t2
apply(t2, 1, function(x) t1[x[1]:x[2], ])
```

Comment: I thought of using for loop and subset() function. But, the apply function seems to be too powerful. Thank you